# Detecting insertion of new components at design-time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, design-time

How can my Delphi component detect at design time if any other component is being dropped on the form?

Comment: -1 You have a good answer, but in comments to it you are imposing lots of constraints not present in the question. That's always frustrating. I suggest you give more detail. Tell us the ultimate goal and maybe we can help.

Comment: -1. I agree with @David. This is an incomplete question based on the comments you've added to the answer below. If you have more specific requirements, they belong in the question itself and not in comments to an answer. The question should be complete itself, and not depend on wading through comments to determine what it is you're actually asking.

Comment: Why have you still not edited your q to state the additional requirements mentioned in your comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override `Notification` method of your component; something like that:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
//..
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
      Operation: TOperation); override;
  end;


procedure TMyComponent.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (Operation = opInsert) and (csDesigning in ComponentState) then begin
// AComponent was dropped on the form
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works well! However, it seems that at this time (Notification), the inserted component is not yet a child of the form. I.e. the inserted component is not yet included in TForm.ComponentCount. My component processes all the components on the form, so in this case the inserted component is not found in my processing.

Comment: I think the inserted component should already be in `TForm.Components` list when the form invokes `Notification` call.

Comment: AComponent.HasParent is false in Notification. Also AComponent.Name is empty and AComponent.DesignInfo is uninitialized in Notification. So there is not much one can do with AComponent in Notification.
I think I will use a Timer which fires only once enabled in Notification to get things done.
Or could there be an other solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use a timer?

Comment: Furthermore, this event is also fired at the time when the project is loaded, once for each component on the form! How could this be avoided?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Because that seems to be the only way to process the inserted component AFTER Notification, since its properties are not yet initialized in Notification.

Comment: Nobody knows what you are trying to do. Read the question and see if you can find anything that talks about parenting, or about processing inserted components properties after initialization. We can't read your mind. Put yourself in our position.

Comment: What I said is a very clear fact: AComponent properties are not yet available in Notification. And I need the properties AComponent.Name and AComponent.DesignInfo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19020/discussion-between-user1580348-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean controls being dropped instead of components, and if you mean dropping on your component rather than dropping on the form, then:

- Add an `CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE` message handler to track controls before they are inserted, or
- Add an `CM_CONTROLCHANGE` message handler to track controls after they are inserted (`WParam` points to the control),
- Don't do this until `csLoading` is out of `ComponentState` to prevent tracking during form creation by the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to track COMPONENTS (not controls) dropped on the form (not on my component). I need the properties of the dropped component to arrange the positions of non-visual components (which already works well). What I need is to do the processing (the arranging of the non-visual components) as soon as the user drops a new component on the form. For this I need the AComponent properties (which are not available in Notification). So the only solution seems to be a OnceTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, if it helps... i am having a similar issue:

- I want to hide non-visual component icon (for my `TMyLabel=class(Classes.TComponent)` component) when i drop it from IDE inside a Form, Panel, etc ...

I have oveloaded: `Loaded` and `ReadState` to get such icon out of sight (at design-time) ... on `Loaded` & `ReadState` i put `DesignInfo` to point to (-100,-100), so icon is not shown

I have oveloaded: `WriteState` to avoid Left & Top be saved to the .dfm  (at design-time) ... on `WriteState` i put it to point (0,0), so it is not saved inside the .dfm

Note: I use same technique/trick to not save properties i do not want, etc ... i really only let Caption to be saved inside the .dfm

The question / tip is:

- When i drop a new "control" (of my component) into the form, such icon is visible just where i drop it... how to hide it?

Maybe `user1580348` is trying something similar ... or something related to auto-align such non-visual "controls" / "components".

In other words:

- How can we control the icon position when dropping a new (our component) control on a form, panel, etc...

I know my problem is much easier, but i did not yet solve it... i want just to hide that icon IDE shows for non-visual components (only for controls that are of my component)... but maybe knowing how to it will also helps `user1580348`.

As i said, it is just a tip/clue.